# Can links be made more visible?

Tags: feature-request, design, links

I posted a question today with a link... which was barely visible, even for me who posted it.

Can we change the color scheme so both **new** and **visited** link are more visible?

In this screenshot there is a link:

> [image: link screenshot]

Do you get it at first glance? I suppose not. Even knowing where it is still remains hard to be seen. In a Beta site, it's much more visible:

> [image: Beta site]

Comment: Well, that would take action on the part of the Stack Exchange web design team: jin and anyone they've gotten in to help him. I'm sure someone will be along to look soon. In the mean time, you could write a User Script.

Comment: @dmckee Yes, I tagged it so that Jin might see it sooner or later. :) Let's hope he does eheheh :P

Comment: JIIIIINNNNNN :-)

Comment: YEEESSSSSSSSSSSSSS!

Answer (score -3):

Look into your web browser's configuration.  You can probably customize this for yourself.

Comment: Yes, I've been suggested that. But the feature-request remains, as it is for the whole site, not just me.